I am trying to pull my main code in my local , it's giving me an error > can someone help me?
remote: Enumerating objects: 142, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (140/140), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (89/89), done.
remote: Total 142 (delta 85), reused 88 (delta 44), pack-reused 2
Receiving objects: 100% (142/142), 26.53 KiB | 405.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (85/85), completed with 10 local objects.
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/main
error: https://github.com/Usama3414/begrow-dashboard.git did not send all necessary objects

I am trying to pull my main branch code in my local VS Code, but it throwing me an error of this

You need to leave enough information for us to be able to replicate this error.  What command are you running?
